# API call using react/redux returns empty object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im new to React and Redux and still confused a little bit.

My goal is to render json datas in the HTML by using GET request. I'm using react and redux to manage the state of the objects, but I believe my problem is that the data is not even there

here is the code:

Action.js :

```
import axios from 'axios';
export function fetchUsers(){
const request=axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/');
return(dispatch)=>{
    request.then(({data})=>{
        dispatch({type:'FETCH_PROFILES',payload:data})

    });
};



}
```

Component.js:

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';


class App extends Component {

 ComponentWillMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(onFetchUser());
 }
   render() {
   
   
    const mappedUsers = this.props.users.map(user => <li>{user.email}</li>)

    return <div>
      
      <ul>{mappedUsers}</ul>
    </div>
  }
  
 }
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    users: state.users.users
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onFetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

CombineReducer.js :

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux"

import users from "./reducer-active-user"


export default combineReducers({

  users ,
})
```

Reducer.js :

```js
const initialState = {
    users: []
};
export default function reducer(state= initialState
  , action) {


    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_PROFILES':
            return   {
      users: action.payload,
      }
        break;
            
    }
    return state;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a dispatch in the axios `.then` callback since its an `async` call

```
import axios from 'axios';
export function fetchUsers(){
        return function(dispatch) {  
                       return axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
                       .then(({data}) => {
                            dispatch({type:'FETCH_PROFILES',payload:data})  
                        });

       }

 }
```

Also in your component you need to call `onFetchUsers` like

```
class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.onFetchUsers()
     }
    render() {


    const mappedUsers = this.props.users.map(user => <li>{user.email}</li>)

    return  (<div>
               <ul>{mappedUsers}</ul>
           </div>
       )
  }

}
```

Comment: Nothing changed, it still returns empty object

Comment: try the solution now

Comment: Still nothing, but for some reason i think the problem is with the component

Comment: console.log(data) in the .then of axios and see if you get anything . Also Try `.then((response) => {})`

Comment: Not working is fine do you get the result of console.log(response)

Comment: Check the update for the component, componentDidMount must be with small case and then call the fetchUsers with props no need to use dispatch

Comment: you need to install  [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware in order to use this mechanism

Comment: @oliv37 Yes, I agree that you need redux thunk with it

Comment: After updating my component and changing the importation to import { fetchUsers } from "../actions/index"  it worked just fine . Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah right did not see that it  was a named export and hence you need to access it like action.fetchUsers and not fetchUsers